# ImageView.Visible and ImageView.Gone is not working android

Tags: android, android-view

I have created code in that when I click on suppose A Image, then B Image should show for 100 Milliseconds and then goes off

I have done this by Java Code

```
public void changeRightDrum() {
    System.out.println("RIGHT");
    imageViewB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imageViewB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    System.out.println("RIGHT DONE");
}
```

But it is not working B image is not displaying

Can anybody help me how to achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `postDelayed` like this.

```
public void changeRightDrum() {
    System.out.println("RIGHT");
    imageViewB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageViewB.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        imageViewB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        System.out.println("RIGHT DONE");
      }
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're blocking the UI thread with `sleep()` and any UI updates cannot really be performed.

Instead of sleeping, use a `Handler` with `postDelayed()` to schedule a `Runnable` to run after a delay.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing what @laalto said :

```
public void changeRightDrum() {
System.out.println("RIGHT");
imageViewB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                   imageViewB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   System.out.println("RIGHT DONE"); 
                  }
           },200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved by using this

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            imgPressedLeftTabla.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            imgPressedLeftTabla.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }.execute();
```